# Change class background on hover

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, cycle

I have table with multiple elements with class like 'rok0', 'rok1', 'rok2' etc. and I want to change background of all elements with same class when hover on any of them. I got this function:

```
$(function() {
  $('.rok1').hover(function() {
    $('.rok1').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }, function() {
    $('.rok1').css('background-color', '');
  });
});
```

This function is working, but i would like to use it for all the classes, so I want to use for cycle on it but somehow it doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
$(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
    console.log('.rok'+i);
    $('.rok'+i).hover(function() {
      $('.rok'+i).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }, function() {
      $('.rok'+i).css('background-color', '');
    });
  }
});
```

and this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
  $(function() {
    console.log('.rok'+i);
    $('.rok'+i).hover(function() {
      $('.rok'+i).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }, function() {
      $('.rok'+i).css('background-color', '');
    });
  }); 
}
```

None of them was working, I have no idea why, can you help me?

Edit: Example of my table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th class='rok0'>Col11</th>
<th class='rok1'>Col21</th>
<th class='rok2'>Col31</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class='rok0'>Col12</th>
<th class='rok1'>Col22</th>
<th class='rok2'>Col32</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='rok0'>Col13</td>
<td class='rok1'>Col23</td>
<td class='rok2'>Col33</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And I want to set background of all element with the SAME class when I hover over one of them.

Comment: 1) Do not use incremental `id` or `class` attributes. They are an anti-pattern which leads to more complex code for absolutely no benefit. Use a common class on these elements instead 2) CSS is a much better solution for this; use the `:hover` selecto

Comment: But I want to change backgroud color for multiple elements with same class when is hover on one of them. Thats not possible with css, is it?

Comment: That is not clear from the question. Can you please add a sample of your HTML to the question showing how the elements are related

Comment: I added example of table to question. I think best solution would be if I find out why the cycle is not working.

Comment: Thank you. I added an answer for you which avoids the need for classes at all. It's really not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `startsWith` `css` attribute in `jquery` and add classes accordingly without any looping.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[class^="rok"]').hover(function() {
    $('[class^="rok"]').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('[class^="rok"]').css('background-color', '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rok1">
  Rok1
</div>

<div class="rok2">
  Rok2
</div>

<div class="rok3">
  Rok3
</div>
```

**Update**

Here's how you can do for same class with startswith `css` selector.

```js
var currClass;

$(function() {
  $('[class^="rok"]').hover(function() {
    currClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.' + currClass).css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }, function() {
    currClass = $(this).attr('class');
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('.' + currClass).css('background-color', '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class='rok0'>Col11</th>
    <th class='rok1'>Col21</th>
    <th class='rok2'>Col31</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class='rok0'>Col12</th>
    <th class='rok1'>Col22</th>
    <th class='rok2'>Col32</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='rok0'>Col13</td>
    <td class='rok1'>Col23</td>
    <td class='rok2'>Col33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works well, but I have more elements with the same class and i want to change background of elements with same class as the element i hover over. I addet example of table to question.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use incremental `id` or `class` attributes. They are an anti-pattern which leads to more complex code that's harder to maintain for absolutely no benefit.

Given the JS/HTML sample in the question it would appear that you are attempting to highlight the cells of the column on hover. As such you can use the `index()` of the elements along with the `:nth-child` selector to make this work in a far more reliable and extensible manner:

```js
$('table th, table td').hover(function() {
  var index = $(this).index() + 1;
  $(`table tr th:nth-child(${index}), table td:nth-child(${index})`).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col11</th>
    <th>Col21</th>
    <th>Col31</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Col12</th>
    <th>Col22</th>
    <th>Col32</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col13</td>
    <td>Col23</td>
    <td>Col33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col14</td>
    <td>Col24</td>
    <td>Col34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col15</td>
    <td>Col25</td>
    <td>Col35</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$(function() {
  var color = "";
  $('div[class^="rok"]').hover(function() {
    color = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }, function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', color);
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  var color = "";
  $('div[class^="rok"]').hover(function() {
    color = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }, function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', color);
  });
});
```

```css
div[class^='rok'] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.rok2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rok1"></div>
<div class="rok2"></div>
<div class="rok3"></div>
<div class="rok4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First give same class to all your elements

For eg:

```
   $('.newClassHere').hover(function(){
    $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() { 
        if (this !== '') {
            classes[this] = this;
        }    
    }); 
      classes.forEach(function(element){
        if(element.substring(0, 3) === 'rok')
           var number = element.substring(3,4);
      });
});
```

> Var number will capture the number you have in your class name
>   for eg: rok1 will give you 1.

```
$(function() {
        $('.rok' + number).hover(function() {
          $('.rok' + number).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        }, function() {
          // on mouseout, reset the background colour
          $('.rok' + number).css('background-color', '');
        });
 });
```